# How do I get a list of custom fields in JIRA with Perl SOAP?

Tags: perl, soap, jira

I was curious if anyone else had an idea how to get a list of all of the custom fields you have created in JIRA?  If so, how did you do it?

I've been trying to use a Perl SOAP routine I found on [JIRA SOAP service documentation](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/index.html?com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html), but I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: You might want to read this article on about a [JIRA Perl client](http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=9623#CreatingaXML-RPCClient-PerlClient).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** You will need admin to access custom fields

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->proxy("http://jira_url/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl") or die $!;
my $login = $soap->login($user,$passwd)->result();
my $cfresult = $soap->getCustomFields($login);
my $cfarray = $cfresult->result;
my %cfhash;

foreach $cfld (@{$cfarray}) {
    $cfhash{$cfld->{'name'}} = $cfld->{'id'}; 
}
```