# Jira SOAP API custom field

Tags: api, soap, jira

Hi I'm am trying to get the list of issues from a JIRA server using the [SOAP API](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+SOAP+Client) provided by JIRA.

I'm trying to filter the issues based on a custom field (and latter I will want to set that custom field).
If I get the list of issue it returns the custom fields for those issues along with them (I get customfieldId, key, values for each custom field) and I can get the custom field with getCustomFields methods provided by the API (to look for the ID of the field with a given name).

The issue I have is that if I login with an account that is not an admin (using the API) I can't call the getCustomFields method (it throws an exception saying I have to be an admin to do that).

My question is: Is there any other way to know which is the ID of the custom field I desire that can be done using a normal user account?

Also if you know how to set a custom field for an issue, it would also be very helpful :) (I would also like to be able to do it with a regular user account).

Answer (score 3):

You have to be an admin to get a list of custom fields. Any 'normal' account can act on the custom fields via the API provided the user knows the customfield ID.

You can set the value of a custom field too, even with a 'normal' account. Again, the user needs the appropriate permissions to do this. Example provided [here](http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=223220267).

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749038/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-custom-fields-in-jira-with-perl-soap) and [here](http://www.customware.net/repository/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=8093738).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [getFieldsForEdit(token, issueKey)](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#getFieldsForEdit%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), which will return `RemoteField[]` for all fields available for edit on that issue (even if it has not yet been defined on the issue).  It does *not* require admin permissions, but because it has the word "Edit" in the method, it does require that you have permission to edit the issue (which means, e.g., if the issue is `status=Closed`, it will raise an exception unless you allow editing closed issues.  Unfortunately, I have yet to find a way to retrieve the RemoteField[] list (in order to map id to name), so `getCustomFields()` and `getFieldsForEdit()` appear to be the only options.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting a list of issues from the project, picking one, zeroing out the data, and using that as a template? That might work.

Answer (score -1):

SOAP is being deprecated in favor of the REST API, which also has a better method to get this information